# What should be the main concerns while writing the research methodology section of a research proposal?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, methodology, research-proposal

According to the research proposal evaluation results I have received, my supervisor advised me to elaborate more on the research methodology I chose. This is a research related to computer science, machine learning in particular. But he did not mention as to what I should write exactly there. Currently I have described my approach similar to software development life-cycle as follows.

Problem Identification – Problem Identification and motivation

1. Collect enough learning materials about the four main subject areas considered.
2. Conduct a literature review and synthesize information.
3. Construct a conceptual framework

Solution Design

1. Develop a system architecture.
2. Analyze and design the system
3. Develop algorithms for the processes.
   4.Choose suitable technologies, environments and materials for the implementation.
4. Implement the system.

Evaluation

1. Test the system.
2. Once the system is error free, up and running use a benchmark workload to test the
   performance of the system.
3. Conclude and summarize results.

I have no idea how I can elaborate this more or to re-write this section properly. Can you please let me know what a good research methodology section is and how to shape up this existing content into a proper methodology section?

Comment: Expand some or all of these bullet points into proper paragraphs. You professor probably wants to to explain *how* you will test the system, rather than just writing "test the system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many machine learning researchers are not necessarily interested in combining an appropriate system architecture with a right *choice* of suitable technologies; they want to *develop new* technologies for the specific problem statement. So ask yourself: what problem am I encountering, and how can I push the scientific knowledge across a gap to solve this problem? What new methodology could I possibly invent to go beyond what already exists?

By the way, your question may be better answerable if we have any clue in which country you're working, and at which level of studies you're encountering these questions. Is this PhD research, an MSc thesis, a Master's course, or BSc education? A supervisor's expectations will vary with these contexts.